# How do I write text lines to file with variables to a file?

Tags: python

I am trying to automate writing a large Silvaco ATLAS (a TCAD software) script with varying values of variables in it through python. So I am trying to write ATLAS code lines to a file but I want to use key/variable values from a dictionary that I have generated in my python code. Any better way to do this?

Let's say the dict in my python looks like,

```
    variable_dict = {'length':22, 'height': 200, 'width':10}
```

(A similar dict but with a lot more keys)
so I was going to write the ATLAS code as follows:

```
    atlas_code = ''' x=%length
                     y=%height
                     z=%width
             '''
```

(a similar ATLAS code but with a lot more lines of code and lot more variables from the variable_dict)

and the write it to a file, like

```
    f.write(atlas_code)
```

I expect the written ATLAS file to look like

```
    #atlas_code.in
    x=22
    y=200
    z=10
```

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Template like below:

```
import string
content = string.Template('x=$length\ny=$height\nz=$width')
f.write(content.substitute(length=variable_dict['length'], height=variable_dict['height'], width=variable_dict['width']))
```